# Discontinuous function in Smooth infinitesimal analysis

Tags: smooth-functions, infinitesimals, synthetic-differential-geometry

I read that there isn't discontinuous functions in Smooth infinitesimal analysis. But I tried to define discontinuous function ($\varepsilon$ is infinitesimal):

$f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $x$ = $\varepsilon$} \\
0, & \text{if $x$ $\neq$ $\varepsilon$}
\end{cases}$

What is mistake in my definition?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*tl;dr* It is not the case that all $x \in R$ satisfy either $x = \varepsilon$ or $x \neq \varepsilon$, so your function is not well-defined.

Let $R$ denote the real line of Smooth Infinitesimal Analysis. What you read is true: in Smooth Infinitesimal Analysis all functions **from $R$** to itself are continuous and in fact differentiable everywhere. This is an easy consequence of the Kock-Lawvere axiom.

Now, the function $f$ you defined is a perfectly well-defined discontinuous function -- from the set $S = \{ x \in R \:|\: x = \varepsilon \vee x \neq \varepsilon \}$ to $R$.

However, $(\forall x \in R. x = \varepsilon \vee x \neq \varepsilon)$ is not a theorem of Smooth Infinitesimal Analysis for any $\varepsilon$: in fact, its negation is a theorem! This is fine, since Smooth Infinitesimal Analysis uses intuitionistic logic, where not all instances of the law of excluded middle ($A \vee \neg A$) are taken as axioms.

Since the negation of $(\forall x \in R. x = \varepsilon \vee x \neq \varepsilon)$ holds, we have $S \neq R$. So your function has domain $S$, and not domain $R$, and consequently its existence does not contradict the fact that all functions from $R$ are continuous.

Comment: Function is not well-defined because there are infinitesimals that indistinguishable from $\varepsilon$. Is it right?

Comment: Yes, that's precisely the issue.

Comment: I read in one book that infinitesimals of higher order can be neglected ($\varepsilon$+$\varepsilon^2$ $\approx$ $\varepsilon$). But in our case we have $\varepsilon$ + $\varepsilon$ $\approx$ $\varepsilon$ (i.e. 2$\varepsilon$ is indistinguishable from $\varepsilon$) .Is it true? (I am little confused because $\varepsilon$ and 2$\varepsilon$ are infinitesimals of the same order).

Comment: 1/2 So, in synthetic differential geometry, if $\varepsilon$ is a nilsquare infinitesimal, then $\varepsilon + \varepsilon^2 = \varepsilon$, you can prove that the two quantities are literally the same since $\varepsilon^2 = 0$. However, $\varepsilon$ and $2\varepsilon$ are indistinguishable in a subtler, weaker sense: you can prove that $\neg (\varepsilon \neq 2 \varepsilon)$ holds, although you cannot necessarily prove that $\varepsilon = 2 \varepsilon$. Since intuitionistic logic lacks double-negation elimination, the negation of non-equality does not imply equality.

Comment: 2/2 Some nilsquare infinitesimals do in fact satisfy $\varepsilon = 2\varepsilon$. For example, $0$ is a nilsquare infinitesimal since $0^2 = 0$,, and in fact $0$ does satisfy $0 = 2\cdot 0 = 0$. So it's not surprising that you can't distinguish between $\varepsilon$ and $2 \varepsilon$ for an arbitrary nilsquare $\varepsilon$: to do that, you'd have to somehow rule out the $\varepsilon = 0$ case, so you'd have to assume $\varepsilon \neq 0$. But then $\varepsilon$ would be invertible, so you'd have $\varepsilon = \varepsilon^2 \varepsilon^{-1} = 0 \varepsilon^{-1} = 0$, a contradiction.